# How can I call a function from controller1 in controller2? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, angularjs-scope

I have a function defined in controller1 and would like to use it in controller2. When I do `$scope.functionName()` or even `$rootScope.functionName()` I get this error

> TypeError: $scope.functionName() is not a function

It works absolutely fine in controller1 but as expected not in controller2. I do not want to copy and paste an existing function into controller2 to use it. It should be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service or a factory and put the function in there. Next, make both controllers use the service/factory by injecting it to both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Use events($on, $broadcast and $emit) to communicate btn two controllers.

Syntax:

$scope.$broadcast("MyEvent",data);
$scope.$emit("MyEvent",data);

$scope.$on("MyEvent", function(evt,data){ 
  // handler code here });
Hope it helps.

Comment: How would the code look like if I wanted to use functionName() at any time in controller2? I don't really get the evt, data layout.

Comment: app.controller('One', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('two', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.childmethod = function() {
            $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
        }
    }
]);        You can use $emit+$on ---Child to parent controller where as $broadcast+$on ---Parent to child controller.